# How to copy CSS properties from one div to another?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some div classes that only change one property (the background property) between them. I was wondering if I can pre-define a standard class and then define all the others with just this one property changed, to save hundreds of lines of code.

Here is what I currently have written:

```
.flex-info-green {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #79B0B4;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-info-blue {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #7993B4;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-info-foam {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #79B47D;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;   
}

.flex-info-pink {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #9B79B4;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;   
}

.flex-info-red {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #B4797F;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;   
}
```

As you can see amongst all of these div classes, the only data that changes between all of them is the background variable. Is it at all possible to define JUST flex-info and then perhaps have separate variables for green, blue, foam etc?

I tried doing this:

```
.flex-info {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-info.green {
  background: #79B0B4;
}
```

and then in the HTML writing it as:

```
<div class="flex-info green">hi</div>
```

But when I placed them all together, the colours would just take the green colour and none of the others. It was very frustrating! I hope you can offer some support.

Comment: Try putting the full name of both css in the class. class="flex-info flex-info-green"

Comment: Since that code work, you must have misspelled something. Next time (also) post the code that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the exact right idea, you simply have to create the additional selectors (such as `.flex-info.blue` and `.flex-info.foam`), and then update the `<div>` elements to reflect the new classes (such as `<div class="flex-info blue">hi</div>` for `blue` and `<div class="flex-info foam">hi</div>` for `foam`):

```css
.flex-info {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-info.green {
  background: #79B0B4;
}

.flex-info.blue {
  background: #7993B4;
}

.flex-info-foam {
  background: #79B47D;
}

.flex-info.pink {
  background: #9B79B4;
}

.flex-info.red {
  background: #B4797F;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-info green">hi</div>
<div class="flex-info blue">hi</div>
<div class="flex-info foam">hi</div>
<div class="flex-info pink">hi</div>
<div class="flex-info red">hi</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: That works fantastically, thank you. That's exactly what I was trying to do! Wonder how I went wrong...

Comment: @josef -- Glad to hear that it worked for you:) It's quite possible you use a space instead of a dot between `.flex-info` and `blue`. In such a case, `blue` would be a `<blue>` element child of `.flex-info`, which isn't what you want according to the HTML structure :)

Answer (score 0):

What you would do is create two classes. One that is generic enough for all the `div` elements and then more specific ones for each particular `div`. You would then apply two classes to each `div`, the generic one and then the particular unique one for that specific `div`.

```css
.allDiv {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-info-green {
  background: #79B0B4;
}

.flex-info-blue {
  background: #7993B4;
}

.flex-info-foam {
  background: #79B47D;

}

.flex-info-pink {
  background: #9B79B4;
}

.flex-info-red {
  background: #B4797F;
}
```

```html
<div class="allDiv flex-info-green">Content</div>
<div class="allDiv flex-info-blue">Content</div>
<div class="allDiv flex-info-foam">Content</div>
<div class="allDiv flex-info-pink">Content</div>
<div class="allDiv flex-info-red">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

```css
.flex-info {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

  .flex-info.green {
    background: #79B0B4;
  }
  .flex-info.blue {
    background: #7993B4;
  }
  .flex-info.foam {
    background: #79B47D;  
  }
  .flex-info.pink {
    background: #9B79B4; 
  }
  .flex-info.red {
    background: #B4797F;  
  }
```

```html
<div class="flex-info green">hi</div>
<div class="flex-info blue">hi</div>
<div class="flex-info foam">hi</div>
<div class="flex-info pink">hi</div>
<div class="flex-info red">hi</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks a lot!